# Philosophical texts which focus on a novel or small idea?

Tags: reference-request

Perhaps an extremely broad question, but I'm looking for philosophical texts which focus on a small/novel idea that the author uses as a springboard to reflect on more general ideas.

For example, the book 'On Bullshit' by Harry Frankfurt does the whole novel concept to broad discussion perfectly. Frankfurt first dissects what it means for something to constitute as bullshit, and ends up giving a great discussion on ideas of lies, truth, etc.

I'm unsure of any other examples, so unfortunately the description of my question is condemned to be quite sparse. Regardless, I'm hoping there's enough merit in the question itself to be taken seriously.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Well, the Phenomenology of Perception of Merleau-Ponty. In the section of 'time' the author quotes various cites (specially from Proust) in order to explain his view of the time.